# Async/await within BeginReceive Callback

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, async-await, asyncsocket

That's been said that the `BeginReceive` and `BeginSend` callbacks are not executed on the .Net `ThreadPool` instead they are executed on the `IOCP ThreadPool`. For high performance servers it is critical for the IOCP threads to return to the pool as soon as possible which mean no heavy lifting within the callback of `BeginReceive` and `BeginSend`. What if I call an async method and await it within the callback.
Does it mean the `IOCP` thread will return to the threadpool and when the async operation will complete the callback method will continue on another available `IOCP` thread?

Comment: Are you asking about an `async-await` method or a BeginX/EndX method?

Comment: @i3arnon async-await

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no guarantee that those callbacks will execute on IOCP threads.

If you make your callback asynchronous and use `await`, then the callback thread will be returned to the thread pool (whether it's an IOCP thread or a regular thread pool thread). Later, when the asynchronous method resumes, it will resume on a regular thread pool thread, not an IOCP thread (AFAIK this is undocumented but just makes sense).

However, I can't imagine a use case where you would actually want to do this. The code would be cleaner if you [wrapped `BeginReceive`/`EndReceive` and `BeginSend`/`EndSend` within a task-based API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873178(v=vs.110).aspx#ApmToTap) and just used `async`/`await` throughout.

Comment: I was creating a scalable server in classical EAP and I was wondering if I could squeeze async-await into it to offload work from the IOCP threads. This ( http://web.archive.org/web/20080209233229/http://www.coversant.net/Coversant/Blogs/tabid/88/EntryID/10/Default.aspx ) was my inspiration

Comment: @AbdullahSaleem: Have you run into IOCP thread starvation? If not, you're solving a problem that doesn't exist.

Comment: When stress testing the response time increase significantly, the probable cause of which can be the unavailability of IOCP threads it can be because of the heavy lifting done in the callback(like querying the DB and other stuff)

Answer (score 2):

If you call and `await` an `async` method the continuation would be executed using a `ThreadPool` thread (unless specified otherwise by a `SynchronizationContext` or `TaskScheduler`, which isn't the case here).

However, you can't make the callback `async` unless it's `async void` which should be avoided. So I don't see how you can reasonably `await` anything in this callback.

It would be much simpler to transform the `BeginX/EndX` into a `Task` with `FromAsync` and then you can handle continuations on it with more control. For example you can specify `TaskScheduler.Defaul`t to make sure that continuation runs on a `ThreadPool` thread.

```
var task = Task.Factory.FromAsync(BeginX, EndX,...);
task.ContinueWith(ante => {...}, null, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default)
```

Comment: the idea was to offload time consuming work from the IOCP thread

Comment: @AbdullahSaleem If you generate a task with `FromAsync` you can add continuations which you can force to run on the `ThreadPool`.